# Polymer: how to parse the index to the elements using template repeat

Tags: html, indexing, polymer, repeat

I've been trying to use Polymer for a project I'm working on. And although I enjoyed it quite a lot so far, I ran into a problem I just can't solve.
I dumped it down to a simple example. Basically it's just a list element (item-list) that contains item elements (item-card) and i want to parse the items position to the element via the attribute pos. But for some reason the items attribute is allways undefined! Is this because the attribute is bound to the variable i, which dies after the template repeat? If so, how do I work around it? Is there a different approach I should be using here?

SOLUTION: You can find the solution by reading through all the comments, but to sum it up: apperantly there was a timing issue and the attribute wasn't ready at the `ready` callback. But I found out about the `domReady` callback ([polymer lifecycle documentation](https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/polymer.html#lifecyclemethods)). Using `domReady` it works just fine! Thanks to Günter Zöchbauer for the help!

This is the item-list.html:

```
<link rel="import" href="components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="item-card.html">

<polymer-element name="item-list">
  <template>
    <style>
    </style>

    <template repeat="{{values, i in data.data}}">
      <item-card pos="{{i}}"></item-card>
    </template>

  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      created: function()
      {
        this.num = 123456;

        this.data = { "data":
          [
            {
              "value":999
            },
            {
              "value":666
            },
            {
              "value":555
            },
            {
              "value":222
            }
          ]
        };
      }
    });
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

This is the item-card.html

```
<link rel="import" href="components/polymer/polymer.html">

<polymer-element name="item-card" attributes="pos">
  <template>
    <style>
    </style>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      ready: function()
      {
        console.log("ready: " + this.pos);
      }
    });
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

I didn't bother putting the index.html in, since it just containts one item-list element.

Thanks alot!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need a `pos` field in `<item-card>` in addition to the `attributes="pos"` declaration.

The repeated element also references the bound model which can be accessed like `querySelector('item-card').templateInstance.model` property.
See https://github.com/PolymerLabs/polymer-selector/blob/master/polymer-selector.html#L286 for an example.

#### Info:

According to the comments it turned out to be a timing issue. The value wasn't yet assigned when the `ready` callback was called but using `domReady` worked.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! But unfortunately adding a pos field to the element didn't make a difference. And I'm not quite sure if I used the templateInstance the way you thought of, when you replied. But I tried accessing pos by using this.templateInstance.model.i inside the item-card. But it also is undefined.
What I just can't understand is, that although i can't get the index via this.pos in the script part, I can just make a paragraph outputing the index in the template part of the item-card element. So <p>{{pos}}</p> works just fine!

Comment: I think `this.templateInstance.model` should work as well. Did you check if `{{i}}` has a value for example by adding it outside of `<item-card>`.

Comment: Yes I did, and it does. I don't know if you noticed, but I also just edited my comment saying that for some reason outputing i in a normal paragraph inside the element works just fine!

Comment: I wouldn't expect this but maybe it is a timing issue that the value is not yet assigned. Can you try to link the `console.log` to a click event on your element?

Comment: Yes, you're right! I just added buttons to output the value onclick and it works! So it seems that it somehow isnt ready at the ready lifecycle. But is there a lifecycle after ready I could use?

Comment: I wonder that `ready` isn't sufficient in this situation. Usually you can workaround this by delaying your code by one cycle using `job()` (see https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/polymer.html#job)

Comment: I just did some additional research and found out about the `domReady` callback and it works! I never heard of the `domReady` callback before, I only knew about the `ready` and `created`, this is good to know! Thanks alot for the help! :)

Comment: I saw the `domReady` but from the description I didn't think it would apply for your problem. Glad you got it working.